# Spring and MVC proper project structure

Tags: java, spring, swing, model-view-controller

I'm developing Swing standalone application using Maven. I try to follow MVC pattern. I'm confused with my project structure. I have something like this:

```
/src/main/java/myName/appName             
/src/main/java/myName/appName/model       
/src/main/java/myName/appName/view
/src/main/java/myName/appName/controller
```

Now I want to incorporate Spring framework, what makes me place somewhere DAO and BO interfaces and implementations. I have read this article [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-annotation-mysql-example/) and the suggested project structure does not suit mine. What crosses my mind is to add this:

```
/src/main/java/myName/appName/dao
/src/main/java/myName/appName/bo
```

The content of dao directory would look like this (with Client and Customer classes in model directory):

```
/src/main/java/myName/appName/dao/ClientDAO.java
/src/main/java/myName/appName/dao/ClientDAOImpl.java
/src/main/java/myName/appName/dao/CustomerDAO.java
/src/main/java/myName/appName/dao/CustomerDAOImpl.java
```

Is this bad? I want to learn good practices.

Comment: Which part of the directory structure in your quoted article does not suit you?

Comment: @Adrian Shum where would you put DAO and BO classes then?

Comment: @Costi Ciudatu why is it bad practice? What to use instead?

Comment: Instead of DaoImpl ? MysqlDao, JpaDao or (worst case) DefaultDao or StandardDao. *Impl means there can be only one implementation or the second will be named *Impl2. There's no need for an interface if there can be only one implementation...

Comment: Sprign does not require interface for each DAO? In every Spring tutorial I have read, all DAOs had their own interface

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can follow any of the two project structure you have defined in your problem but that should depend on your application size.

If you have a large amount of modules in your application than you can follow the project structure as described by @basijames. Because that will be helpful in managing the code and distributing the work in your team.

If you don't many modules then I prefer you should go for project structure something like below.

```
/src/main/java/myName/appName/controller   
/src/main/java/myName/appName/model
/src/main/java/myName/appName/service
/src/main/java/myName/appName/dao
/src/main/java/myName/appName/bo
```

But according to me while creating a maven project you should skip the selecting archtypes.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Answer (score 18):

The categorisation

```
/src/main/java/myName/appName/model        
/src/main/java/myName/appName/view 
/src/main/java/myName/appName/controller
```

will cause problems for you later. 
The package structure mentioned in the link you provided should suit you. You should have one package for each module/entity.
Eg `/src/main/java/myName/appName/customer`
 and you should put all `model`, `view`, `controller` and `dao` classes related to `customer` in this package.

Comment: I thought it would be good to separate view from model. What if I have view class that is not related to any of the entities? Where should I put it? And also, is it neccessary to create separate folders for model, dao and bo, and then in dao and bo separate folders for implementation? I would like to have something like this:`/src/main/java/myName/appName/customer/Customer.java`, `/src/main/java/myName/appName/customer/CustomerDAO.java`, `/src/main/java/myName/appName/customer/CustomerDAOImpl.java`, `/src/main/java/myName/appName/customer/CustomerBO.java` and BO implementation.

Comment: The common classes if any can be put in a folder like `../appName/common/`. For an entity `../customer/bo` and ../customer/dao` can be added for other classes it can be direclty in `../customer`. Name your dao implementation like `MySqlDao` or `<SpecificDB>Dao`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why it will cause problems?