# Spring MVC - Project structure - best practices

Tags: spring-mvc, projects-and-solutions

What's the best approach?

1- Create multiple projects:

[image]

2- Create a single project:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring and MVC proper project structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397940/spring-and-mvc-proper-project-structure)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I'd suggest you take a look at Spring's Project Sagan.  It's the source code for their current website (http://spring.io).  While they used a multi-module approach, it wasn't divided as you are suggesting.  They really just pulled out some client work and kept the rest in a single module.

This site was written by the Spring team the way they would use their own tools and released as a reference application to answer questions just like this.  I encourage you to take a look here: https://github.com/spring-io/sagan.

NOTE:

> The spring.io website is not using the sagan application in production anymore. This repository is now archived.

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful in many aspects, but not what I was thinking... I don't even see a WEB-INF folder, web.xml, etc...

Comment: That is by design.  There typically is no need for a web.xml anymore.  With regards to a WEB-INF directory, the WAR structure is built via the build scripts themselves.

Comment: Your answer lead me to this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tEm0USdF-70 which was the structure I followed. Thanks

Comment: Another guidance I found from their documentation specified another structure though https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

Comment: @MichaelMinella: can you please tell me where is the routing file resides ?

Comment: @MichaelMinella How can I import it is eclipse, it seems to have so many components like sagan-client, sagan-indexer etc. What is the use of each of those components?

Answer (score 3):

The point is to ask yourself what is the point in separation. If you are planning to run them in different containers on different servers, then it makes sense. If it is a large project, it makes sense to separate.