# Java Classes Structure

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc

I am working to a project made in Maven with Spring and i want to start the structure fine from the beginning.

I need help from you to know if is ok what i did until now. So, in have the structure: 
src/main/java/com/fabbydesign/controller
src/main/java/com/fabbydesign/model
src/main/java/com/fabbydesign/util

and i have another file in:
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appConfigs.xml
in this file i store the configurations of the project, like database login, etc

In the directory utils, i will store utils class for the project. for example, i will make a class that will read the appConfigs.xml to get configurations stored there

Is ok what i did until now?

In the model directory, i have to store the beans for the database, or i can add other types there? Like, the bean for the xml with configs?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397940/spring-and-mvc-proper-project-structure and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550273/spring-mvc-project-structure-best-practices

Comment: ok, 10x, i will do like there!