# Spring project structure

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, project-structure

I am working on my first spring project, at the moment I can still manage the project but I think when I am going to add more controllers and entities I am going to lose the overview.

In this answer I saw that I should split it up https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399383/2735398

But I am still curious, is there an structure standard? I normally work in Laravel, here is the structure already predefined, and to find, create or delete a model you only need only class. In Spring I need for example an User Entity, Service and a Repository. So I already have 3 times as many files for each table.

The application is just an API. So I don't use any templates(Maybe later for mail).

At the moment I have these folders:
**config** package: This contains all the class with the @Configuration Annotation, like the websocket config and the interceptor registration.

**controllers** package: This contains all the controllers.

**database** package: This contains all the Services and repositories to get entities.

**entities** package: This contains all the entities.

**interceptors** package: This contains all the interceptors

**services** package: This contains all the self made services that can be injected, like a `AuthService`.

**validation** package: This contains all request validation, for example is the password long enough.

Comment: There's no standard structure.

Comment: There is no standard or convention for where to place your Spring components.  What you've defined seems to make sense, you'll probably find yourself adding a few more as you code along (exception, handler, etc). One recommendation I'd make is to drop the 's' off the package names, they're implied plural.