# Resource vs Controller in a Spring MVC project

Tags: spring-mvc

I have seen some projects using a package named "resources" and some other projects using a package named "controllers", to put RestControllers. Which is the most common convention for a package name that contains rest controllers? If I'm writing rest controller for accessing user service, should the controller be named UserController or UserResource?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397940/spring-and-mvc-proper-project-structure

Answer (score 0):

Both meaning the same, but Controller is more common. UserController is ok

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

> Controller

Is for Spring MVC

> Resource

Is for Jersey